# Excel ER diagram SQL Server import data tables using .NET code (Excel Add-in)

Tags: .net, sql-server, excel, er-diagram

I would like to import data from SQL tables into an Excel sheet and upon doing so, I would like to show the ER diagram of these sql tables. Whats is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the picture of the diagram to the clipboard and paste it in a Word doc.

Comment: IMHO a better answer would be "paste it into the Excel sheet" ;-)

Comment: easier to resize to match the page in Word, but whatever works.

Comment: My bad I should have elaborated. I need to build an Excel Add-In using C# and .Net code. Under the Data Menu(Ribbon) in the Excel sheet, one has the option of importing the data from multiple databases, this is one such case where I import data from SQL Server and I should be shown the ER Diagram of the data tables in the DB.

Comment: I don't think you can import a database diagram on a SQL Server database, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Beth's answer: you will need a tool for creating an ER diagram. If you don't have one at hand, read this SO post:

[SQL Server to er model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055159/sql-server-to-er-model)

EDIT: if you don't want to build your own ER diagram layouter by yourself (something I would not recommend), you should try to find a third-party component for that. Don't expect to get that for free. Here is one capable of creating ER diagrams:

ActiveX edition: http://www.mindfusion.eu/flowchartx.html

.NET edition: http://www.mindfusion.eu/flowchart-net.html

(disclaimer: I do not have anything in common with the vendor, and I did not try it by myself).